# Collapse data for each line angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a table with several lines, in each line I have a column in with a link that will allow me to collapse data concerning some line. The probleme I'm having is no matter which link I click on, it's always the first line that's collapsing.

```
 <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="formation.uniteEnseignement.length">
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <strong><span class="fa fa-university"></span> Unités d'Enseignement</strong>
                 <table class="table" >
                    <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>Semestre</th>
                         <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                         <th>Elements Constitutifs</th>
                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                         <tbody >
                            <tr ng-repeat="ue in formation.uniteEnseignement">
                                <td ng-click="edit(ue)">{{ue.semestre}}</td>
                                <td ng-click="edit(ue)">{{ue.uniteEnseignementPK.codeFormation}}-{{ue.uniteEnseignementPK.codeUe}}</td>
                                <td ng-click="edit(ue)">{{ue.designation}}</td>
                                 <td> 
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">  

                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                          <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                              <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#{{ue.uniteEnseignementPK.codeFormation}}" href="">
                                             Collapsing details  </a>
                                            </h4>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="{{ue.uniteEnseignementPK.codeFormation}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                                     <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="ec in ue.elementConstitutifCollection" >
                                                          <table  ><tr><td>{{ec.designation}}</td></tr></table>
                                                     </div>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </td>

                            </tr>                    
                        </tbody>
                </table>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: issue is same id repetition for multiple `panel-groups`

Comment: but isn't getting a different value everytime I affect {{ue.uniteEnseignementPK.codeFormation}} to data-target and id?